# Highstock/Chart created from html table fails if null value in first table row

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a Highstocks graph with multiple line series from an html table using the data module,  however if any value in the first row of the table is Null (empty) the chart fails.  If I change the empty values to 0 then the chart does then appear.  This only happens for the first row, if the following rows contain null values there is not a problem.  Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Would need to see your chart code with the offending source table. But, in general, you should account for instances like this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, so I reported that to our developers here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5336. Thanks